# Cannot use socket.io with redis on Heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, socket.io

I am trying to use socket io on Heroku with RedisToGo. In local environment, everything is fine.

When I deploy my code to the Heroku, most of the time I am getting 400 Bad Request with following data from the browser:

```
{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
```

My redis config is:

```
var url = "redis://redistogo:xxx@lab.redistogo.com:xxxx/";
var rtg   = require("url").parse(url);

var pub = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname, {return_buffers: true});
var sub = redis.createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname, {return_buffers: true});
pub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);
sub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1]);

var redisOptions = {
  pubClient: pub,
  subClient: sub,
  host: rtg.hostname,
  port: rtg.port
};

io.adapter(ioredis(redisOptions));
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Heroku accepting only websocket transport. Setting transports to websocket both in server and clients solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling session affinity on the Heroku app should fix the *Session ID unknown* error, you can do this by running

```
heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
```